# Extract JSON data from C# nested dictionary object using JavaScriptSerializer()

Tags: c#, json, api

While attempting to extract data from `JSON` using `JavaScriptSerializer`, particular difficulties are encountered while looking through the `data` of `object` type.
Based on the below sample data, the following code has been written:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic outp = serializer.DeserializeObject(out3);            
var a = outp["Number"]; // is OK, returns "1"
var b = outp["Description"]; // stuck in looking through "Description" to access "address", then extract the value of "street_2", as an illustration.
```

Feedback (not involving *ideally* the definition of a `class` with related `properties`) would highly be appreciated. Thanks.

```
{
  "Number": 1,
  "Description": [
    {
      "id": "PO1234",
      "country": "TE",
      "No": "4050",
      "safeNo": "LU37",
      "name": "stuck",
      "address": {
        "street_1": "adhoc, 0098, country",
        "street_2": "94 street",
        "city": "stackoverflow",
        "zip": "stack"
      },
      "is_EU": "Y",
      "conti": "E",
      "date": "2019-08-14T21:43:02.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: *not involving ideally the definition of a class*, is this because the JSON is dynamic?

Comment: *Not at all*. I guess (*modest opinion*),  that solutions involving dictionaries would *relatively* be more efficient, particularly if one have many data from different queries to be extracted.

Comment: I think using a class then is the neatest option. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Description` is an array, you can egt the first item by index and access its properties by key, in the same way with `Number`. Under the hood every item of `Description` (as well as address) is `Dictionary<string, object>`

```cs
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic outp = serializer.DeserializeObject(out3);  

var a = outp["Number"]; 
var b = outp["Description"][0];
var name = b["name"];
var street = b["address"]["street_2"];
```

However, using [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8) isn't recommended, you should use [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) instead

Comment: Very `smart` approach with the `indexation` (:) , and your tip in relation to `JavaScripSerializer` has been appreciated. Many thanks, `Pavel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Newtonsoft.Json` to deserialize it like that:

```
static string Test()
{
    var filePath = "../../../response.json";
    var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(text);

    var data = result
        .GetValue("Description")
        .Select(t => t.Value<JObject>("address"))
        .First()
        .Value<string>("street_2");

    return data;
}
```